# Paperclip CloudFiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, cloudfiles

How can I use Paperclip with CloudFiles? I found [paperclip-cloudfiles](https://github.com/meskyanichi/paperclip-cloudfiles), but in the description it says it will probably be removed and the last commit was in 2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gemfile:

```
gem 'fog'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
:path             => ":picturable_name/:basename_:style.:extension",
:storage          => :fog,
:fog_credentials  => {
  :provider           => 'Rackspace',
  :rackspace_username => RACKSPACE_USERNAME,
  :rackspace_api_key  => RACKSPACE_API_KEY,
  :persistent         => false
},
:fog_directory    => CONTAINER_NAME,
:fog_public       => true
})
```